Dynamics of a drifting car
Assuming we know the properties of a moving car (static friction, dynamic friction, force applied by wheels, velocity, heading, mass, wheel rotation, etc.), when does the car drift and what are the dynamics of a drift? is there an equation to describe the threshold at which it starts drifting? I know it has to do with overcoming static friction but how do we determine this if the wheels are not accelerating the car and it's just moving because of inertia?

Welcome to Physics SE. If you know all the properties of the car, then you should be able to tell pretty much anything about it, but you'll have to define "drifting". Is hitting the brakes to stop the wheels turning while the car is moving forward in a straight line considered drifting? It's going to end up just dealing with the friction forces involved.
